# javascript syntax errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a little trouble trying to implement a plugin on to my site, im pretty new to js and im having a little trouble getting my head around the syntax.. The part im having trouble with bellow is the lines `#mm-prev` and `#mm-next`.. Have i added those bits correctly ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
              jQuery(".jbgallery").jbgallery({
                 fullscreen: false,
                 style : "zoom",
                 randomize : 1,
                 menu : true,
                 slideshow:false,
                 caption : false
              });  

              jQuery("#mm-prev").click(function(){
                   obj.left(); 
              }); 

              jQuery("#mm-next").click(function(){
                  obj.right(); 
              }); 
        });  
</script>
```

the html those last parts go with is

```
        <a id="mm-next" href="#">NEXT</a>
        <a id="mm-prev" href="#">PREV</a>
```

for a bit of background the script in question is [JBgallery](http://www.ymic3dworld.com/lightwindow2/jbgallery-3.0/index.html)

Comment: is this the whole of the code - from script to /script ?

Comment: can you show your divs? #mm-prev and #mm-next should be id's inside your div's e.g. <div id="#mm-prev"></div>

Comment: Could you please tell us what the error is?

Comment: How's `obj` defined..my guess is it should be a reference to `jQuery(".jbgallery")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `obj` it looks like you should be selecting `.jbgallery`:

```
          jQuery("#mm-prev").click(function(){
               jQuery('.jbgallery').left(); 
          }); 

          jQuery("#mm-next").click(function(){
               jQuery('.jbgallery').right(); 
          });
```